# Date format to be loaded using sql loader

Tags: sql-loader

I have 03-JUN-2012 16:06:54 format. How do I do this using SQl loader.While using this in control file I used 
Start date "dd-mmm-yy HH:MM:SS" but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following in the control file

start date "dd-mmm-yy hh24:mi:ss"